# Do resistors of same color code but different size have the same resistivity?

Tags: resistance

Picture has three resistors with the same color code (in this case brown-black-black) but different sizes.

My question is if they have the same resistivity because I know resistivity is indicated by color code.

[image: resistors of different sizes with same color bands]

Comment: @manludo, welcome to EE.SE! Note that, more effort put into question formatting and syntax encourages others to put in the time to answer.

Comment: @manludo I've submitted an edit to your question that changes "measured by" to "indicated by" -- the color bands are just paint, and some resistors don't have them at all. Not sure if this is simply a language issue or an issue of understanding the purpose of the bands.

Answer (score 34):

> resistor of same color code but different size have the same resistivity?

No, they have the same *resistance*.  Resistivity is a bulk property of material.  Since the geometry of each resistor is different, it is quite likely that the resistivity of the material the resistors are made of differ between the resistors.

The resistance, however, is the same (within tolerance, looks like 5%) between each of the resistors.  It's a little hard to tell, but the color bands seem to be BRN,BLK,BLK.  If so, then each resistor is 10 Ω ±5%.

The two main differences between the large and small resistors are:

Power capability.  Large resistors can dissipate more power before getting too hot.

Voltage capability.  Larger gap between the leads usually results in higher voltage handling.  For such relatively low values, the maximum voltage can only occur in short spikes, else the resistor would get too hot.  This metric is more relevant for high-Ohm resistors where the voltage is not limited by power dissipation.

Comment: When using large and small resistors with the same power, the larger ones hopefully will be less hot.

Comment: @Uwe And, while size *can* be in indicator, the datasheet is king.

Answer (score 9):

They have the same resistance.

*Resistivity* is a bulk property of a material. These three resistors are likely all made of carbon film (wrapped around some kind of central core). They might all be made with the same material, or they might be made of slightly different materials with different resistivity.

The advantage of the larger part is mainly greater power handling capability. At the same internal temperature, the larger part will shed more heat to the atmosphere around it, so it will not heat up as much for the same current.

Comment: “With the same current flowing through it, the larger part will shed more heat to the atmosphere around it” – actually no, with a constant current both will eventually shed the same power in heat, namely \$R\cdot I^2\$. The point is that the larger part is able to shed that much heat already whilst at low temperature, whereas the small one first needs to get pretty hot so convection will do the job effectively enough despite the small surface area.

Comment: Is it really considered dissipating heat if the resistor blows up?

Comment: @leftaroundabout actually yes, note the "to the atmosphere around it" specifier. They dissipate the same power, yes, but the bigger one will give more of it to the surrounding, while the smaller one will heat up more because of the heat it cannot shed.

Comment: @SredniVashtar that would mean it would heat up indefinitely. Which _may_ happen, kind-of, if you apply too much current (it heats up until it burns through), but normally it only heats up until the heat given to the surrounding compensates the electrical energy it consumes.

Comment: @leftaroundabout The way I see it, they reach different kind of equilibria: one with very hot body because of smaller dissipating surface, the other with cooler body because of the bigger surface. But I reckon that in the energy balance one has to consider mass as well: in the limit, a bigger enough resistor will transfer less heat to the surrounding atmosphere, since almost all energy will be used to raise its body's temperature (which will be lower, not only because there is more surface to shed it off, but also because there is more mass). There must be a bell shaped curve somewhere...

Comment: @leftaroundabout, fair point. Edited.

Comment: @SredniVashtar leftaround is right. If they're generating the same amount of heat (\$I^2R\$), they need to be shedding the same heat at equilibrium. The bigger one will be able to do that at a lower temperature.

Comment: They don't need to have exactly the same resistance, they should be all within the defined tolerance band. The gold ring indicates the tolerance.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience with small throughhole resistors.

The colour of the bands gives you the resistance (not the resistivity, resistivity is a property of a bulk material not a component) and the tolerance

The background colour usually indicates the technology, the beige colour in your picture generally means carbon film while a light blue background generally means metal film. Other colors are likely more special types.

For carbon film resistors the body size normally relates to the power rating. ⅛W carbon film resistors are about 3mm long and about 1.8mm in diameter. ¼W carbon film resistors are about 6.5mm long and about 2.5mm in diameter. ½W carbon film resistors are about 8.5mm long and about 3mm in diameter. 1W carbon film resistors are about 11mm long and about 5mm in diameter

I think your two smaller resistors are ⅛W and your larger resistor is ¼W but since your picture has no reference for scale it is difficult to be sure.

For metal film resistors the power rating is sometimes but not always higher than a carbon film resistor of the same body size. It is not uncommon to see 0.4W metal film resistors in a "⅛W" body size and 0.6W metal film resistors in a "¼W" body size. However it is also common to see metal film resistors with the same power rating as carbon film resistors of the same body size.

Comment: Background color doesn't have any bearing, according to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5204/57453  Do you have a source?

Comment: Other than years of buying resistors from multiple different manufacturers suppliers, no. I guess it was originally one manufacturers convention and the rest copied it.

Answer (score 2):

**Resistance**

Yes, the resistance is similar, the color code only decides what the resistance is (plus/minus some accuracy, also color coded).

**Wattage**

However, what is not color coded is the wattage (how many Watts the resistor can handle). Mostly bigger resistors have more wattage 'capability'.

The small resistors in your picture are probably 1/8 W (see comment from J below), and the bigger ones 1/4 W. Both are suitable for microcontroller usage.

**Test**

If you want to be sure about the resistance, use a multimeter. If you have many and you don't mind blowing one, you can use a small circuit to let one melt to know how many Watts it can bear.

Comment: @J... That could be true ... I only have a lot of blue ones which are 0.25W but hard to say if those are bigger, and my 'whitish' ones are 0.5W.

Answer (score 2):

Resistors come in different sizes depending on how much power they can safely dissipate.  Larger packages dissipate higher wattage.  No matter what the size, the color code is the same.

For non-cylindrical and some large cylindrical resistors, the resistance is indicated with letters and numbers printed on the package.

What you have in your picture look like 1/2 W and 1/4 W resistors.

Comment: Looks to me more like 1/4 W and 1/8 W but it's hard to be sure without a scale reference.